# Commas in a sentence "if not... then", and why

Tags: commas

I struggle with commas. Not sure if it's because I never learnt any grammar, I have unusual breathing habits, am oddly polemical in speech, or what exactly. Anyway

Should you include (the) commas in sentences such as

- I am, if not stupid, then dim.

And why (be as technical as you want)?

In general: any help with commas?

Comment: Placement of commas is often as much about style as grammar. That said, your sentence would read very oddly without any (and sound odd if spoken without pauses).

Comment: Commas are often used to indicate major syntactic breaks which in speech are expressed with pauses of varying duration.

Comment: So if you know how you would say something aloud so that it sounds "natural" to your ear, you can feel confident when putting a comma in those places where you'd pause, especially with a longish pause.  And if you're writing something and cannot get it to sound natural when spoken aloud, find a different wording.

Comment: Following Kate's and Tim's Comments, I'd also suggest that up until roughly the inter-WWI & II period, both the commas in that exposition would have been mandatory, and in the particular example they prolly still are.

In the particular instance, there's little leeway but during the decades between, much slack has slipped into many another expression with three such parts, which would now sport only a single comma.

Dropping them all would be too much but any of my commas, here, is optional - and wouldn't '… oddly polemical in speech or what, exactly' work just as well?